# Swift protocol in Objective-C class

Tags: objective-c, swift

I wrote `SearcherProtocol` in Swift and need to implement an Objective-C class `FileSearcher` which has to use this protocol.

So I tried this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FileSearcher : NSObject <SearcherProtocol>

// ... class content

@end
```

The compiler tells me

> Cannot find protocol declaration for 'SearcherProtocol'

The corresponding bridged header file (`modulename-Swift.h`) is being imported within `FileSearcher.m`.

Importing `SearcherProtocol` into `FileSearcher.h` throws another compiler error: `module name-swift.h file not found`

Does anybody have any clue what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using Xcode 6 Beta 5.

**Edit**

Here is the protocol declaration in Swift:

```
@objc protocol SearcherProtocol
{    
    var searchNotificationTarget: SearchCompletedProtocol? { get }
    var lastSearchResults: [AnyObject] { get set }

    func search(searchParam: String, error: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool
}
```

And the SearchCompletedProtocol:

```
@objc protocol SearchCompletedProtocol
{
    func searchCompletedNotification(sender: AnyObject!)
}
```

Comment: Is the protocol declared with `@objc` flag?

Comment: Yes, it is. Looking into the generated header file tells me it's there.

Comment: Could you show us the protocol declaration?

Comment: Sure. I will post it tomorrow (I'm out of office now).

Comment: If anyone is finding that their Swift Delegate protocol isn't found and they're using both Objective-C and Swift, it's because you're missing the @objc flag.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**There are two common reasons for this occuring:**

1. Getting the module name wrong, see my answer.
2. Having a circular reference - see mitrenegades answer below.

**1. Get the module name right:**

If both the swift protocol and and Objective C are in the same project then according to [apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) you should just need to make sure you get the correct module name.

For Xcode6 beta 5 you can find it under BuildSettings->Packaging->Product Module Name

A common mistake would be to think that each swift file/class gets its own file, but instead they are all put into one big one that is the name of the project.

A further mistakes are if the module name has spaces, these should be replaced with underscores.

Edit:

With your protocol I created a test project called 'Test' which compiles perfectly and it has the files:

TestObjClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Test-Swift.h"

@interface TestObjCClass : NSObject <SearcherProtocol>

@end
```

TestObjClass.m

```
#import "TestObjCClass.h"


@implementation TestObjCClass

@end
```

TestProtocol.swift

```
import Foundation

@objc protocol SearcherProtocol
{
    var searchNotificationTarget: SearchCompletedProtocol? { get }
    var lastSearchResults: [AnyObject] { get set }

    func search(searchParam: String, error: NSErrorPointer) -> Bool
}

@objc protocol SearchCompletedProtocol
{
    func searchCompletedNotification(sender: AnyObject!)
}
```

**2. Avoid circular reference:**

Mitrenegades answer explains this, but if your project needs to use the explicit objc class that uses the swift protocol, (rather than just using the protocol) then you will have circularity issues.  The reason is that the swift protocol is defined to the swift-objc header, then to your obj-c class definition, which then goes again to the swift-objc header.

Mitrenegades solution is to use an objective-c protocol, is one way, but if you want a swift protocol, then the other would be to refactor the code so as to not use the objective-c class directly, but instead use the protocol (e.g. some protocol based factory pattern).  Either way may be appropriate for your purposes.

Comment: The module name is not the problem. I'm able to import it into the Objective-C source code file. CMD + click on the imported file also works (shows me the code Xcode generated for the Swift code - and there I can see both protocols).

Comment: I have tested the protocols, and probably unfortunately for you, they work fine for me, would you like a copy of the project?  I will update my answer too...

Comment: You say you can see the Xcode generated swift code, which suggests you don't have any small errors in the protocol, which obviously can cause issues...  Could you post the full files?

Comment: I tried this in a separate project, as well, and it compiles without issues. But: Trying to create an instance of `SearcherProtocol` like `let a: SearcherProtocol = TestObjClass()` throws an error that `TestObjClass` does not conform to protocol `SearcherProtocol`.

Comment: Then you would need to either make the protocol's methods / variables optional, or actually make them in TestObjClass - did you manage to make it work in the original project?

Comment: No, I didn't get it working in that project. Perhaps this is a pretty weird issue which may be caused by the fact that this project has been created with the first Beta of Xcode 6. I chose a slightly different approach: left out the protocol for the Objective-C class and check the presence of required selectors manually. At least this seems to work as expected. Thank your all for your effort. I marked your answer as "accepted" because this is the way it usually works (which it does, indeed).

Comment: Don't know why this is the accepted answer. Importing module swift headers in .h file will throw compile errors.

Comment: Its a perfectly normal thing to import module swift headers in .h files - there are no compile errors unless you have circular references.  I've edited the answer to make this clear.

Comment: For me, the issue was that I didn't have the @objc flag ahead of my protocol declaration. Adding that exposed it to the objective-c class and fixed the compiler errors.

Answer (score 28):

When you have

```
#import "moduleName-Swift.h"
```

in the .h file that you want to be a delegate, and you have that .h file also in the bridging headers file, there's a circular reference that causes the moduleName-Swift.h to fail compilation. for @james_alvarez's test project, it's probably working because you don't need to include TestObjClass.h into the bridging header.

The best way for me to combine objc files that need to be the delegate for a class written in swift, but that also needs to be included in the bridging header so other swift files can access this objc class, is to create a separate protocol file in objc:

MyProtocol.h:

```
@protocol MyDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)didDoThis;
-(void)didDoThat;

@end
```

ViewController.h:

```
#import "MyProtocol.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MyDelegate>
```

MyProject-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "MyProtocol.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
```

Comment: great answer. I had the same problem - Swift header file was not found when imported in .h file, eventually I found I had circular reference (although not direct), and defined the protocol in separate objc file. Thanks !

Comment: I particularly like the fact that this solution separates out the protocol from both the Obj C and Swift classes, emphasising its man-in-the-middle status.

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. The answer from @james_alvarez is not full proof.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 23):

I know this was a long time ago, but I just struggled with the same problem when adding a protocol to my Swift code, and it wasn't being added to the -Swift.h header file, hence "Cannot find protocol declaration"

The problem was my protocol wasn't marked as *Public*. I changed my protocol from this:

```
@objc protocol MyProtocol { //etc.... }
```

to this:

```
@objc public protocol MyProtocol { //etc.... }
```

I'm still not entirely sure why I need 'Public' but nobody else seems to, but hey it works...

Comment: Another interesting observation: it appears that only the Protocol needs to be marked with the `@objc` annotation. The class gets added automatically (even without the `public` modifier)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are including the auto generated Swift header in your ObjectiveC file.  It will have the same name as your project module followed by `-Swift.h`.

For instance if your Project Module is **MyTarget**, then you would use:

`#import "MyTarget-Swift.h"`

If you are typing in the import into your Objective C file, it will not autocomplete.  You can verify that you have the correct file by Command-clicking on the header after typing it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the conformance part from Swift side

So you have a swift `protocol` and want to make an Objective-C type conforms to it,

**Swift Side**

Add `@objc` to your protocol to make it visible to Objective-C world.

```
@objc protocol IndianCooking {
  func cookChicken()
}
```

**Objective-C Side**

In the implementation `.m` file you do the following:

```
#import "YourProject-Swift.h"
@interface Cheef ()<IndianCooking> { 
}
```

and in the header file `.h` add the method
`cookChicken()`

Answer (score -2):

Import delegate as like this in .h file

```
@protocol AnalyticProtocol;
```

and add this in to .swift file

```
@objc public protocol AnalyticProtocol {

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try adding `#import "Product_Module_Name-Swift.h"` to your `Product_Module_Name-Prefix.pch` file.  That fixed it for me, plus you will now have access to your swift files from any objc file.

Comment: That's a really bad advice. High probability for creating circular imports. Using precompiled header just to share something to all your headers is abuse of the precompiled header. Nowadays just ignore the precompiled header and don't put anything there.