# Short-circuit when using a Swift protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, protocols

As known, it is not possible to include the interface header file from a file in the -Header.h.
My actual problem is that I have the definition of a class one protocol of which is a Swift one:

```
@protocol arrivingDelegate;

@interface palettaTraffic : NSObject<MKMapViewDelegate, arrivingDelegate> {
}
```

If I import the *-Swift.h file I get into the ugly cycle when the file is included in another one that is included in the header file.

This is what happens when I use the @protocol directive: it is a warning, but quite a disturbing one.

[image: Screen-shot with the warnings]

This is how the swift protocol is defined:

```
@objc public protocol arrivingDelegate {
    func submitManualBusLine(busStripe:StripeProtocol)
}
```

I also found a similar post:
[Swift protocol in Objective-C class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266137/swift-protocol-in-objective-c-class)

But none of the suggestions seem to apply.

Comment: The same way as you would a class: `@protocol StripeProtocol;`

Comment: I added a screen shot for the warning happening when I use the @protocol directive in one specific case. The one that probably convinced me I could not use the technique. Yet in other files it works fine, for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adopting swift protocols in Objective-c is a tricky process. I fixed the issue by porting the adopting class to Swift too.

Answer (score 0):

> If I import the *-Swift.h file I get into the ugly cycle when the file is included in another one that is included in the header file.

Okay, but that is what you have to do. I don't see you doing it the screen shot above, which is why your protocol is not being seen.

The solution to the "ugly cycle" should be just a matter of tweaking the *order* in which things are imported in your various Objective-C files.

Comment: I posted a revised screen-shot, where the errors have turned into warnings.

Comment: The reason it isn't worse than a warning is that the `@protocol` directive merely means "Trust me, compiler, there is such a protocol." So the compiler _does_ trust you and sure enough, at runtime it turns out you were telling the truth. But surely you would prefer to get rid of all warnings eventually.

Comment: I know the story, but eventually at linking time all piece should come back in order. I ignore why this specific issue does not. If that thing lasts, I shall also translate to Swift that class for the good.

Answer (score 0):

What I tend to do in my projects is putting the protocol conformance of the ObjC class in a Swift file, to avoid this error. Usually the file where the protocol is defined.

```swift
extension PalettaTraffic: ArrivingDelegate {}
```

Why? We're migrating our codebase from ObjC to Swift, but we cannot migrate every class at the same time. Because of this we have a large 'seem' between Swift & ObjC where Swift types need ObjC and vice versa. For me, this is the solution that causes the least amount of work right away.