# References to a class just ported to Swift appear as forward class objects

Tags: objective-c, swift

I just ported a new class to Swift to overcome [an issue with protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31629825/short-circuit-when-using-a-swift-protocol) I had encountered. Yet, after finally fixed all issues associating to the porting, all references to the methods of the class in other objective-c classes are reported as:

> "Property ... cannot be found in forward class *SwiftClass*"

I found a few references to this problem on the web in which it seems the order of inclusion matters, but in all of my class the *-Header.h inclusion is the last one. What could be the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact this time it was right even if the error reporting is sadistic. I had capitalized the class to adopt the Apple suggestion notation expecting the compiler to guide me in the renaming; instead all references to the old name, rather than reporting a normal error consequent to a missing class, reported that funny error taking very far away.

Yet now I get an even funnier error on the alloc operations:

> No known class method for selector 'alloc'

... that weird component...!

Answer (score 0):

This one is fixed by remembering to inherit from NSObject in the Swift class. In brief the lesson is to be absolutely not creative when porting classes to Swift, at least when not yet experienced, as the error messaging is misleading, to say the least.